# HTTP Parse Error in Nodejs when running in a Docker Container

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, http

I have a Nestjs Application which I try to run in a docker container. It all worked fine just until recently where I get the error `Parse Error: Missing expected CR after header value`. I'm trying to make a http GET Request to a webserver of an IoT device. Furthermore this error occurs only when I run the server-app inside a docker container. When I run it locally on a windows or macos machine everything works fine.

I tried using different versions of nodejs in docker. 14, 16 and 18. This error always comes up, independent of which version I use. I have no idea how I could debug this error, since it only occurs when I serve the app inside a docker container.

This is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:slim
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY src .
COPY package.json .
RUN apt update && apt install python3 make g++ -y
RUN npm install --force
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
```

Comment: Could you post some code ?

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile

Comment: it sounds like your client is not fully HTTP compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43798), this was recently implemented in Node v14.20.0, v16.16.0 and v18.5.0. Apparently it fixes a vulnerability in the HTTP parser of earlier versions.

Comments below the issue suggest various workarounds if it's not possible to fix the client, the easiest of which seems to be to set the `insecureHTTPParser` flag to `true` when creating the HTTP server.

Alternatively, revert to an older minor version of each of the Node.js versions mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped me already to find some light in this dark. Weird issue... I will check if I can solve it now using your advice.

Comment: Downgrading to a lower minor version of nodejs did the job for me. Thank you!